# undefined geo location

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I am trying to obtain the client's current location using google's jsapi, but I am getting 'google.loader' as undefined. ANy idea why this could occur? Given below is my code snippet i used.

```
$.getScript('http://www.google.com/jsapi', function() 
{
if(google.loader.ClientLocation) {
var visitor_lat = google.loader.ClientLocation.latitude;
var visitor_lon = google.loader.ClientLocation.longitude;
var visitor_city = google.loader.ClientLocation.address.city;
var visitor_region = google.loader.ClientLocation.address.region;
var visitor_country = google.loader.ClientLocation.address.country;
var visitor_countrycode = google.loader.ClientLocation.address.country_code;
console.log("Your location is: " + visitor_country);
}});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're only loading `http://www.google.com/jsapi` which is the basic `google` library, you can use that library to load the actual google modules, like 'ClientLocation'.

Use something like:

```
google.load("my_library", function () {
    google.my_library; // is not available
}
```

Change `my_library` to whatever you need.

Comment: If you look at the source code the `ClientLocation` gets populated with actual data already.

Comment: Unknown, the script creates `window['google']['loader']`, see for yourself: http://www.google.com/jsapi

Comment: But again, why is `google.loader` `undefined`? It should have been defined then.

Comment: How did you edit the code snippet above that gave you results? It doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: @TheZ When I run it I get an "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'latitude' of null"

Comment: @TheZ It says 'google.loader.ClientLocation' not loaded. Does it work fine for you?

Comment: @vasa It does for me, I would tell you to try Frit's method but there's no ClientLocation module available but if you can find a relevant one go for it: https://developers.google.com/loader/#AvailableAPIs

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem today.

If you are using phone browser, and if you have the localization disabled for the browser, the api not load correctly and throws an js error (Parse error).

I have test it with a iphone and android phone.

Turn on localization for the browser and works fine!